# is there a difference between these lines in `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Tags: debian, apt

In [a guide for installing a wireless card](https://wiki.debian.org/rtl819x#Debian_7_.22Wheezy.22), I'm told to add the following lines to `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
```

This is what my `sources.list` file already looks like (skipping the residual commented out line from the CD installer):

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main

# wheezy-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-updates main
```

Keeping in mind that the wiki article may be several years older than the current Debian version, my question is, are `http.debian.net` and `ftp.us.debian.org` different, or will both URLs retrieve the same packages?

If they are basically the same, instead of adding an additional line of the config file, should I instead edit the first line to this? or will that give me incorrect packages?

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the addresses are different (they are both load balancers so both will send you to different servers depending on where you are & when you query)
**BUT** both URLs should retrieve the same packages, so **yes**, you can add the contrib & non-free pools to the deb line you're already using to get the same result.

You can check what you're getting by visiting the archive with your web browser to see the dates on the files, particularly the files in the indices directory at (http/ftp server of your choice)/debian/indices/

If they've got current dates (preferably some time in the past 24 hours) then check the timestamps on the files. If they're the same on both servers you're good, because they are both mirroring the same source & have both refreshed recently enough to have pulled the same update.

If you're ever using a repository that's not a complete Debian mirror, you can use the same trick of looking through the files/directories under /debian/ via your browser to see which repos & packages are available.

---

If you're interested in why there are different URLS:

If you lookup ftp.us in DNS, the results change (i.e. it's a DNS based load balancer) whereas http.debian.net is an HTTP redirector.
i.e. when you visit the URL for the archive on that host, it bounces you to a repository archive on an appropriate server. (Have a look here http://http.debian.net/demo.html to see how it works.)

If the mirrors are up-to-date (and I would expect these official Debian branded ones *to* be), then both URLs should retrieve the same packages.

Answer (score 1):

`http.debian.net` is Debian's mirror redirector.

If you live in the US, you can keep `ftp.us.debian.org` instead and simply, as you guessed, add `contrib non-free` to `deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main` instead of creating a new line.